# Single click blocks double click in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a GUI where I bind two events to a label like this:

```
self.label.bind('<Button-1>', self.single)
self.label.bind('<Double-1>', self.double)
```

the problem is that, even if I double click the label, the 'double' function isn't called, and the 'single' function is called twice.

It looks like the single click event is blocking the double click event as, if I remove the single click event line, I can normally call the 'double' function.

I read the docs and from what I got it should catch both events, but this is not the case.

Anyway, I tried this simple script and it catches both events

```
from tkinter import *

def single(event):
   print('single click')

def double(event):       
   print('double click')

widget = Button(None, text='Hello event world')
widget.pack()
widget.bind('<Button-1>', single)
widget.bind('<Double-1>', double)
widget.mainloop()
```

Then I don't understand why it doesn't work in the first script. I can post the entire file if needed. Thank you :)

Original File: https://github.com/matte980/ExplorerFile/blob/main/ObjectsPublish.py

Comment: Since you have an example that does what you want, you need to figure out what's different between that example and your code. If you find a "minimum working example" that shows the incorrect behavior, you can post that here.

Comment: When i try this, i get "single click" when i click once and "single click double click" when i double click.

Comment: Do you maybe have a typo in your original code ? Post the original file please

Comment: @Programmer yes in fact it catches both events

Comment: You need to give us a [mcve] that reproduces the behavior you're asking about. It looks like you've given us code that does _not_ have the behavior you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem is that when you make the first click you are calling move() which calls elements(), which *recreates all the widgets*. Therefore your second click is the first click to a new widget.

To solve this you need to update the widget properties, instead of recreating the widgets with new properties. For example, to update the background colors:

```
def select(self, event):
    print('selected')
    for folder in folderList:
        if folder.backgroundColor != '#ffffff':
            folder.chg_background('#ffffff')
    self.chg_background('#ffff00')

def chg_background(self, color):
    self.backgroundColor = color
    self.image.config(bg = color)
    self.label.config(bg = color)
    self.frame.config(bg = color)
```

This will also solve the problem of your program lagging after long use.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, an easier way of holding both events is defining separate functions and calling both functions in one main function.
Like so:

```
def function_one(event):
    #Events
def function_two(event):
    #Events
def main_function(event):
    function_one()
    function_two()
```

So then you can call only one function that traps both events.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, it was a silly thing.
In the 'single' function I was calling a method that redrew the label so that it couldn't catch the second click.